# Why doesn't Franck-Hertz experiment ionize the gas?

Tags: experimental-physics, ionization-energy

In the Franck-Hertz experiment, electrons are accelerated through a gas and their kinetic energies are measured. This produces peaks and troughs which are indicative of changing energy states in the electrons bound to the gas particles. But the results are consistent (for Mercury and Neon) even when you increase the accelerating potential above the ionization potential of the gas!

How come you can apply a high voltage without ionizing the gas or seeing discharge?

I am stumped, any help is massively appreciated.